# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{…}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class

Tags: java, android, eclipse, logcat

I am developing an app using Fused Location Provider. I am getting an error "Unfortunately, appname has stopped" when i attempt to run the program. Eclipse doesnt show that there are any mistakes but there are errors in the logcat. I dont know how to fix them. I downloaded source code [here](http://www.kpbird.com/2013/06/fused-location-provider-example.html). Please help me to understand what I did wrong?

LogCat

```
11-05 08:31:41.641: E/AndroidRuntime(795): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-05 08:31:41.641: E/AndroidRuntime(795): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.kpbird.fusedlocation/com.kpbird.fusedlocation.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.kpbird.fusedlocation.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.kpbird.fusedlocation-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.kpbird.fusedlocation-1, /system/lib]]
11-05 08:31:41.641: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2137)
11-05 08:31:41.641: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
11-05 08:31:41.641: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
11-05 08:31:41.641: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
11-05 08:31:41.641: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-05 08:31:41.641: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-05 08:31:41.641: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
11-05 08:31:41.641: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-05 08:31:41.641: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
11-05 08:31:41.641: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
11-05 08:31:41.641: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-05 08:31:41.641: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-05 08:31:41.641: E/AndroidRuntime(795): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.kpbird.fusedlocation.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.kpbird.fusedlocation-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.kpbird.fusedlocation-1, /system/lib]]
11-05 08:31:41.641: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
11-05 08:31:41.641: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
11-05 08:31:41.641: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
11-05 08:31:41.641: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
11-05 08:31:41.641: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2128)
11-05 08:31:41.641: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: post your AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since your exception is:

```
ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.kpbird.fusedlocation.MainActivity"
```

into your `AndroidManifest.xml` add the complete package were your activity is located:

```
<activity
                android:name="com.kpbird.fusedlocation.MainActivity"
```

or be sure to have to correct package name defined:

```
package="com.kpbird.fusedlocation"
```

**I think you typed incorrectly the package of your application in some place of your code!**

[image]

Comment: I tried this but it still doesnt work. I am developing a project to determine the position of people in emergency call. So it is very important for me. Could you please try this source code on your computer to understand problem?

Comment: yep i got in my eclipse right now i just had to add the reference of google play services library :|, i think you typed incorrectly the package in some place of tyour code! :(

Comment: Thank you for helping me :). I am checking my code again. I hope find the problem.

Comment: you´re welcome, i think is better/faster download and import the project again =).

Answer (score 10):

In my case the issue was with gradle

I refactored my code from java to kotlin but forgot to add this in Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
```

Comment: Thanks! If like me you were using .kts files for gradle then add `plugins { id("kotlin-android") }` to your app level gradle file

Answer (score 1):

This happened when I moved an app from one directory to another once, if [@Jorgesys's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26768748/3124150) doesn't help, consider renaming the module and cleaning the project. Note: I was using Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurred when you change package name in manifest file but not in main activity .
remember when you changing package name then change it on
1 manifest file
if your building flutter then change it on all 3 mode profile , debug , and release
2 main activity kotlin or java file

3 In build gradle change the application id

Answer (score 0):

The same issue occurs while including in `AndroidManifest` reference with:

```
  <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

and hardcoded wrong `google_play_services_version` value.

Answer (score 0):

While updating my MainActivity.java I accidentally changed my package name from `package com.ppg;` to `package com.PPG;` (upper case instead of lower case). When I changed back to lower case it started working.

Answer (score -6):

After spending much time on this problem i finally got the solution.

Just remove `setContentView(R.layout.LAYOUT_NAME);` from constructor of class
and put it into `onCreate` method of the class.

100% it will be solved.